Autograd returning None
I am trying to create a Contractive Autoencoder, and I read in a couple of papers that the main idea is to use the norm of the Jacobian of the encoder's output with respect to its inputs.
In other words, I'm trying to obtain the gradients of the encoder's output while using the original input.
So far, I have something like this:
def compute_model_loss(self, predX, X, latent_X):
    gradients = torch.autograd.grad(outputs = latent_X, inputs = X, grad_outputs = torch.ones_like(latent_X),
                                    create_graph = True, allow_unused=True)[0]
    
    print(gradients) # None!
    frobenius_norm = torch.mean(torch.norm(gradients, p = 'fro', dim = (1,2)))
    
    contractive_penalty = self.args['lambda'] * frobenius_norm
    total_loss += contractive_penalty

The problem arises when computing the gradients in the first line. For some reason, it returns None, so what I've first tried is to see what the data looks like.
Input data X: (32 x 2866)
tensor([[0.4663, 0.3859, 0.6573,  ..., 0.7819, 0.0822, 0.3332],
        [0.4204, 0.8448, 0.6168,  ..., 0.2698, 0.3503, 0.3372],
        [0.6329, 0.4084, 0.7437,  ..., 0.3490, 0.4902, 0.8333],
        ...,
        [0.3004, 0.6908, 0.7698,  ..., 0.8115, 0.9253, 0.1996],
        [0.6895, 0.6812, 0.4595,  ..., 0.8959, 0.6600, 0.5660],
        [0.5647, 0.2448, 0.5046,  ..., 0.6494, 0.4483, 0.5269]],
       device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward0>)

Encoder's output: (32 x 32)
tensor([[0.3837, 0.3975, 0.5000,  ..., 0.6480, 0.9503, 0.8660],
        [0.4182, 0.5000, 0.8683,  ..., 0.4916, 0.7044, 0.5293],
        [0.5000, 0.7034, 0.5588,  ..., 0.3750, 0.5000, 0.5000],
        ...,
        [0.4598, 0.4478, 0.9167,  ..., 0.8179, 0.7026, 0.5000],
        [0.5000, 0.5370, 0.4786,  ..., 0.4529, 0.3132, 0.4245],
        [0.4134, 0.5000, 0.4898,  ..., 0.4799, 0.5000, 0.7334]],
       device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward0>)

So both these tensors do have a computational graph... All these tensors also have requires_grad_ set to True.
Regarding the autoencoder architecture, it's mainly just linear layer after linear layer, and my forward function looks like:
def forward(self, x):
    encoded = self.encoder(x)
    decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
    return decoded, encoded

As for the training part:
x_batch = torch.tensor(tr_model.X_train[b]).to(self.device)

x_batch.requires_grad_(True)
x_batch.retain_grad()

# h is the encoder's output
x_pred_batch, h = tr_model.model.forward(x_batch)

# Here we compute the contractive loss
loss = tr_model.compute_model_loss(x_pred_batch, x_batch, h)

If it helps, when I do loss.backward() with a normal autoencoder, everything works fine. (though I don't use the encoder's output there)
Thanks a lot for reading this far!!
EDIT ::
The encoder's architecture:
 self.encoder = torch.nn.Sequential(
            custom_block(input_dim, 3000),
            custom_block(3000, 2500),
            custom_block(2500, 2000),
            custom_block(2000, 1500),
            custom_block(1500, 1200),
            custom_block(1200, 1000),
            custom_block(1000, 800),
            custom_block(800, 600),
            custom_block(600, 400),
            custom_block(400, 300),
            custom_block(300, 150),
            custom_block(150, 100),
            custom_block(100, 50),
            custom_block(50, L),
            torch.nn.Sigmoid()
        )

where custom_block is:
def custom_block(input_dim, output_dim, dropout_rate=0.4):
    return torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Linear(input_dim, output_dim),
        torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(output_dim),
        torch.nn.PReLU(),
        torch.nn.Dropout(dropout_rate)
    )


Can you show how you obtained latent_X?

Hi Ivan, I obtain it from the forward method. I return both the reconstruction (decoded) as well as the latent representation (encoded)

I see, can you provide the header of compute_model_loss?

Of course, you can see it in the first block of code, where I try to compute the gradients

It seems h is not attached to X but I couldn't reproduce the error with a minimal model. Maybe you can share the implementation of encoder, too?

Sure thing, you can find it at the end of the post. Thanks for still trying :)

I'm afraid I can't reproduce the error, even with the provided model. Did you make sure you were executing the function outside a no_grad scope? I would recommend you add a breakpoint right before the grad computation to inspect h.

I managed to "make it work" by swapping the inputs and outputs arguments in torch.autograd.grad, meaning I'm obtaining the gradients of X with respect to the latent representation.
I'm not sure if this is the intended course of action, so I'm going to review it all and make sure I understand what's going on
Thanks again for the help!!

You mean grad(outputs=X, inputs=latent_X, ...)? Are you sure you haven't swapped around the inputs when you called compute_model_loss?

Yeah exactly.
It's very weird, right before computing the gradient X is 32 x 2866 and latent_X is 32 x 32.
Also, both of them have requires_grad set to True, and a valid grad_fn field. (sigmoid)
